# Calling Navigator outside Widget build() gives context error

Tags: flutter, navigation

So I'm basically trying to check if users have seen an Intro page in my flutter app. If they already have seen it, I want them to be directed to the `Login()` page. Else, I want them to be directed to the `IntroScreen()` page.

However, I am getting the following error: `Unhandled Exception: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator. E/flutter (13982): The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget.`

This is my code:

```
void main() => runApp(CheckSplash());

//check if the intro screen has already been seen
class CheckSplash extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CheckSplashState createState() => _CheckSplashState();
}

class _CheckSplashState extends State<CheckSplash> {

  bool _introseen=true;
  Future checkIntroSeen() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool _introseen = (prefs.getBool('seen') ?? false);

    if (_introseen) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
          new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => Login()));
    } else {
      //await prefs.setBool('seen', true);
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
          new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => new IntroScreen()));
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    new Timer(new Duration(milliseconds: 200), () {
      checkIntroSeen();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: appTheme,
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Builder(
            builder: (context) => Scaffold(
                resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
                body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.red[300])))
            )
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I solved the problem by using the flutter `GET` library. Link: [flutter get library](https://pub.dev/packages/get)

Using this library, one doesn't need the context to navigate between pages and thus it is a full proof method to navigate from anywhere in flutter.

Comment: Pasting the necessary code snippet is recommended

Answer (score 1):

I Have tried the easiest way. Create a function for your code after your contextBuilder. Then, Just put the **context**
as a function argument:

```js
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ....(your code)
}

yourFunction(context) {
  Navigator.pop(context);
  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginScreen()));
}
```

It is worked as expected for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`context` inside `initState` is available inside `SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback`. This function fired after widget is built.

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    new Timer(new Duration(milliseconds: 200), () {
      checkIntroSeen();
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I'm getting the same error